# Internal link doesn't work

Tags: html

I have a link `<a href="#intro">Introduction</a>` to a part of my page below, which contains `<h4 name="intro"> Introduction </h4>`. But it doesn't work. I've tried changing the `h4` to `a`, but it doesn't work either. How can I make it work?

Comment: Use ID instead of (or in addition to) name. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your `name` on your `h4` to `id` :)